# POSTGRES - How do i optimize this join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table as below which stores employees details

| empid | attribute | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | Active | FALSE | 2020-01-01 | 2022-05-05 |
| E1 | Active | TRUE | 2022-06-06 | 9999-12-31 |
| E1 | Branch | NYC | 2022-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| E2 | Active | TRUE | 2020-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |

Then another table which have address details

| empid | city |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | CON |

What I want is

1. List of all the employee ids which do not have entries in address table

AND

2. All those employees whose current value(today's value) of attribute ACTIVE is TRUE.

I have written below query but its taking too much time to execute (3-4mins).
Is there any way i can optimize this query.

```
select distinct(emp.empid) from schema1.employees emp, schema2.address add 
where emp.empid = add.empid 
  and (emp.attribute ='ACTIVE' and emp.val in ('TRUE') 
  and CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN emp.start_date and emp.end_date)
  and emp.emp_id not in (select empid from schema2.address add2)
limit 20
```

Comment: #1 `select * from employees e left join address a on a.empid = e.empid where a.empid is null`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I want a single query which satisfies both the condition. i cannot have two queries

Comment: Is `DISTINCT` really necessary? I would guess there's going to be only one ACTIVE row for an employee in any specific date.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes that is true.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is typically faster than `NOT IN` and if you replace the (ancient) join between `employees` and `address`  with an EXISTS condition you can also get rid of the DISTINCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made only minor modifications to your query that could help performance.

```
select emp.empid
from schema1.employees emp
left join schema2.address add on emp.empid = add.empid 
where emp.attribute ='ACTIVE' 
  and emp.val = 'TRUE'
  and emp.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE 
  and emp.end_date >= CURRENT_DATE 
  and add.empid is null;
```

The following indexes that can be useful as well. If you don't already have them, add them and try again.

```
create index ix1 on schema1.employees (attribute, val, start_date, end_date);

create index ix2 on schema2.address (empid);
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't know where `vpd` came from (probably some gremlin). Now, the predicate `add.empid is null` is there to implement an anti-join; that is, all rows in the left table that do not have a match in the right table.

Comment: This did improved performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the description it's unclear how your two conditions should be combined.

To get all employees that pass **either of your two conditions**:

```sql
SELECT e.empid
FROM   schema1.employees e
WHERE  e.attribute = 'ACTIVE'
AND    e.val  -- = true
AND    CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN e.start_date AND e.end_date
OR     NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM schema2.address a WHERE a.empid = e.empid);
```

To get all employees that pass **both of your two conditions**:

```sql
...
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM schema2.address a WHERE a.empid = e.empid);
```

Assuming you only added `DISTINCT` (incorrectly with parentheses) to deal with duplicates introduced by the join. Not duplicating rows with an `EXISTS` expression in the first place, we also don't need `DISTINCT`.